# Access environment variable in perl written in double quotes via config file

Tags: perl, environment-variables

I have an environment variable **$ROOT**. For eg. $ROOT = "/someroot" It is accessed in a Perl file via config file parameters.

Eg
In config file :
`path = '$ROOT/abc/somepath'`

In Perl file while using this variable when I write config->{$path} in back ticks `config->{$path}` value of $ROOT is accessible i.e /someroot/abc/somepath but when in double quotes "config->{$path}" the result is $ROOT/abc/somepath.
I need this to be written in double quotes for opening files : `open (filehandle,"config->{$path}");` How can achieve the value of config->{$path} in double quotes.

P.S I have also used $ENV{'config->{$path}'};

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
my path = $ENV{"ROOT"} . config->{$path};
open(filehandle, path);
```

But now you do not have to precede your configured path with $ROOT.

> config file: path = '/abc/somepath'

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
sub get_conf {
   my ($config, $key) = @_;
   my $val = $config{key};
   return undef if !defined($val);

   $val =~ s{\$ROOT\b}{$ENV{ROOT}}g;
   return $val;
}

my $path = get_conf(config, 'path');
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more general solution, try one of the [String::Interpolate](https://metacpan.org/search?q=String%3A%3AInterpolate) modules on [CPAN](http://metacpan.org).  I favor [String::Interpolate::RE](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Interpolate::RE) (disclaimer: I wrote it):

```
use String::Interpolate::RE 'strinterp';

my $path = strinterp( $config{path}, {}, { useENV=> 1 } );
```